# authentication requires a valid Date when I connect to AWS S3

Tags: linux, shell-script, aws

I want to download(GET) file from Amazon AWS S3, and I want to write the commands into a shell script.

But I always get the error message:**AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header**.
I'm sure that my key are all right.

Here is my s3.sh from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658147/download-private-file-from-s3-using-bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
s3key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
s3skey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
file=/aaa.pdf
bucket=test
date=$(date +"%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")
echo $date
content_type='application/x-compressed-tar'
string="GET\n\n$content_type\n$date\n/$bucket$file"
signature=$(echo -en "${string}" | openssl sha1 -hmac "${s3skey}" -binary | base64)
curl -H "Host: $bucket.s3.amazonaws.com" \
    -H "Date: $date" \
    -H "x-amz-date: $date" \
    -H "Content-Type: $content_type" \
    -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3key}:$signature" \
 https://$bucket.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com$file
```

and it always shows the error message:

`<Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header</Message>`

anyone has ideas?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script uses the following value for date

```
date=$(date +"%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")
```

The script you reference uses a different date format.  As that other format works ok, change your script to follow that.

```
dateValue="`date +'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'`"
```